# lightning input component labels transaltions

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, translation

Is it possible to add the translations for the messages displayed by default in standard lightning component?

For example for minlength attribute we will receive tooShort: Your entry is too short. I want to translate this message to different languages.

Comment: You can use custom lables and then get it translated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom labels.Using custom labels you can translate to different languages.

Please check this Post:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BKvhIAG

then use custom labels in your lightning component:

- $Label.c.labelName for the default namespace
- $Label.namespace.labelName if your org has a namespace, or to access
  a label in a managed package

for more Information check this document:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm